# League of Legends on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, wine, launcher, games, playonlinux

I'm just new in Ubuntu and my English is so bad, so be patient to me. I was install League of Legends with PlayOnLinux, installation was without errors, but, when i want to run it, a logo is appeard and it's gradually be more dark, like a suspended process. What can I do with it?

Comment: You'd have better chance of getting a useful answer on the PoL forums.

Comment: Try [this](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2020528).

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [League of Legends is on a bronze list](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=10436) in Wine compatibility base, so it will probably won't work correctly under Ubuntu.

Comment: n.b. now rated 'gold'....